# amCharts Custom legend with values (correct method and alignment)

Tags: amcharts

I'm currently building a heat map, with a 100+ data points (Country, value).

I've created a custom legend to only display the top 10 countries and their values.

However the alignment is off (wrong side and the distance between the name and values), is there a better way to do this?

```
chart.legend = new am4maps.Legend();
chart.legend.position = "right";
chart.legend.data = [];

for (let index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
    chart.legend.data.push({
        name: legend_data[index]['id'],
        fill: colorSet.next(),
        value: legend_data[index]['value']
    });
}

chart.legend.labels.template.text = "{name}: {value}%";
chart.legend.itemContainers.template.paddingTop = 2;
chart.legend.itemContainers.template.paddingBottom = 2;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Very simple answer, I just needed to set the valueLabels text, rather than concatenating both into the legend label text. Aligns correctly now.

```
chart.legend.labels.template.text = "{name}";
chart.legend.valueLabels.template.text = "{value}";
```